# Is there a way to have query in Google Sheets list all the cells in a column that are above a cell containing a specific text?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

`=QUERY(offset(XX,3,0):offset(XX,- 1,3), "SELECT J WHERE G > (SELECT MAX(G) WHERE G CONTAINS 'STOP')")`

This range is 4 columns. Real offset input:

```
offset(INDIRECT("'O SHEET'"&"!"&ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)))),3,0):offset(INDIRECT("'O SHEET'"&"!"&ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)))),MATCH("*"&$T$1&"*" , 'O SHEET'!G:G, 0)-MATCH($T$3, 'O SHEET'!G:G, 0) - 1,3)
```

I attempted using the code above, and I get an error stating:

> "Unable to parse query string for Function Query parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "G "" at line 1, Column 16. Was expecting one of: "("..."("...

`=QUERY(G1:J75, "SELECT J WHERE G, H, I > 'STOP' ", -1)`

I tried this, and I understand why only eliminates the row containing 'STOP' but I am unsure how to continue are make things work after this. Any help or tips would be gladly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you update with some information about why are you using that offset? And provide some sample data. That may help to understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
=A1:INDEX(B:B,XMATCH("STOP",A:A)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Ty for this suggestion!

I guess my problem is more sophisticated than I described since my range involves involves 4 columns in the form of OFFSET(XX,3,0):OFFSET(XX,-1,3), eg:

offset(INDIRECT("'O SHEET'"&"!"&ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)))),3,0):offset(INDIRECT("'O SHEET'"&"!"&ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(ROW('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)),SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD)*('O SHEET'!$A$1:$AD=$T$3)))),MATCH("*"&$T$1&"*" , 'O SHEET'!G:G, 0)-MATCH($T$3, 'O SHEET'!G:G, 0) - 1,3)

Comment: Hence the reason why I think query would work best since I am attempting to have the stop in the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd column, but print the value of the 4th column. I will update my question to reflect accordingly.